# Spyder 4 - deactivate automatic highlighting of last word after few seconds

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

When I stop typing in Spyder 4, all occurrences of the last word are automatically highlighted after about two seconds. Is it a bug or can I disable it?

I use Spyder on Ubuntu 18.04.

[image: the highlighting]

Comment: this is quite puzzling that this is a default behavior - I suggest this NOT be the default behavior

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I found the setting: Tools > Preferences > Editor > Display > Highlight occurrences after