# Restore file tabs above main editor in Spyder

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

I was modifying the layout in Spyder 4.1.1 and somehow lost the filename tabs (names of opened .py files) that used to appear above the central editor window.  These were the tabs that had the 'X' button in them that allowed you to quickly close them.  I've been toggling options in the View and Tools menus but can't seem to get it back.  Anyone know how to restore this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) You can restore the tab bar in our editor by going to the menu

`Tools > Preferences > Editor > Display`

and selecting the option called `Show tab bar`.

Comment: Great, that did it.  Thank you.  One other question related to the preferences:  How do I toggle off the automatic highlighting that highlights all terms with the same name as the term where the cursor is placed?

Comment: Please mark my answer as correct by clicking on the green check mark to the left. And also please open a new question about "How do I toggle off the automatic highlighting that highlights all terms with the same name(?)".

Comment: I accepted your answer and found the answer to my other question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60747047/spyder-4-deactivate-automatic-highlighting-of-last-word-after-few-seconds.  Thanks again for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try it. From menu View --> Panes --> Editor. Clicking on Editor and putting a tick there should bring that back if I understand your question properly