# How to disable green highlight in Spyder

Tags: spyder, highlight

does anybody knows how to disable the green highlight in Spyder editor as I show in the picture below?
Thanks[image]

Comment: Does this [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60747047/spyder-4-deactivate-automatic-highlighting-of-last-word-after-few-seconds answer your question or is it more general highlighting you wish to stop?

Comment: sadly it doesn't. The green thing is still there, for example every time I write a loop like for i in range(0...) and it highlights everything I include between the parenthesis.

Comment: I don't quite believe the answer Ive just put up since it seems rather hacky - change the highlight color so it 'blends in' with the background rather than getting rid of it altogether. However, in the absence of any other ideas I put it up in case it gives at least a temporary fix.

Answer (score 1):

Spyder has many settings which the user can change.

In `Preferences>Tools>Appearance>Edit Selected Scheme` we can select the colors of several highlights, including current cell. (followed by OK then Apply, which can take a few seconds, then OK).

Setting this to `#19232d` (which seems to be the color of the overall dark theme background) at least gives the appearance of highlighting having been stopped.

There seems to be no way of setting such a color to transparent (in the CSS sense).

Under `Tools>Preferences>Editor` it seems as though we can unset highlighting of the current cell, but this appears to get overwritten by the `Highlight Occurrences after` selection, and setting that to something huge in the hopes it would not kick in did not seem to work.

However, I do not claim to be a Spyder expert and would welcome feedback from those who are and who perhaps know of ways of stopping highlighting in certain areas completely.

Answer (score 0):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) This is caused by a [bug](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/13908) in our code. It'll be fixed in our **4.2.0** version, to be released in November 2020.

In the meantime, the solution is to reactivate the option `Highlight current line`, present in the menu `Tools > Preferences > Editor > Display`.